# php 5.6.7 fwrite vs fputs utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, fwrite, fputs

I have a xml data that is sent as a string in a url.

For example url?data=string

This is sent to another server that I do not have control over and they use fputs so I can not simply change to fwrite.  I am trying to figure out how to make the fputs work so that I can give them the fix.  My test environment is using php 5.6.7.

In the string is the character á (alt+0225).

Using this code the character is still á when I view the file in notepad++.

```
 $datafile = fopen("datafile.txt", "a");
 foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value){
      $y = "$name: $value\n";
      fwrite($datafile,$y);
 }
 fclose($datafile);
```

Using this code the á is turn into something else when viewed using notepad++.

```
 $datafile_fputs = fopen("datafile_fputs.txt", "a");
 foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
      $y = "$name: $value\n"; 
      fputs($datafilefputs,$y);
 }
 fclose($datafile_fputs);
```

I have attempted this as found here on stackoverflow and the character is still displayed incorrectly.

```
 $file = "datafile_fputs";
 $datafile_fputs = fopen($file, "a");
 foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
      $y = "$name: $value\n"; 
      $file = "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$file;
      fputs($datafile_fputs,$y);
 }
 fclose($datafile_fputs);
```

Anyone know why fputs acts differently and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only solution that I could come up with.  When running the below code into a file, using getallheaders, the fputs of the $_REQUEST['data'] worked.  I assume the header of the file is set to the BOM of utf-8 and therefore everything that is entered after it is properly encoded.

```
 $file = "datafile_fputs";
 $datafile_fputs = fopen($file, "a");
      foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
           $y = "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; 
           $y .= "$name: $value\n";
           fputs($datafile_fputs,$y);
  }
  fputs($datafile_fputs,$_REQUEST['data']);
  fclose($datafile_fputs);
```